# JasperReports Server permissions doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I created new user - **'exampleuser'** and new role - **'examplerole'** in *JasperReports Server* version 5.6.

The new user - **'exampleuser'** has 2 roles: **'examplerole'** and **'ROLE_USER'** that is attached to the user by default in the *JR Server*.

For every folder in jasper I gave the **'examplerole'** and **'ROLE_USER'** the permissions - Execute only.

According to my understanding, if I will login with the **'exampleuser'** user I won't be able to see any folder, of course not be able to delete any file inside that folder.

What actually happens is that I'm able to see all the files inside any folder, add and delete files as I wish and change permissions to the files.

Could not find any information about it - according to the *JasperReports Server* manual I'm not doing anything wrong or do I?

The **'exampleuser'** doesn't have any permissions to the folder e.g. 'NO ACCESS' permission.

And there were no errors in the logs.

Is someone ran into this situation before? Is it fixable or it is some bug of *JasperReports Server*?

-----------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------

I've found out that this situation happens only in Google chrome browser. If I use IE for example, everything is as it should be.
Anyone? Any idea?

Comment: There is no reason this behavior should be browser-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Edit user(exampleuser) and assign only new role(examplerole) which you created for new user remove ROLE_USER and save.

Now right click on the folder on which you want to give permission to new user(exampleuser) and select "Permission" , there you can see all the roles and there access permission.

Change permission No Access to Read only for examplerole and remove the access form other roles i.e. select No Access option.

Now after that you need to check remaining other directories whether they have ROLE_USER access or not , if they have remove permission from ROLE USER i.e set it to No Access.

Comment: Did it already. after I logged in as exampleuser in this situation I could not see any folder as it says that I don't have the permissions to access the root folder. After searching the cause, I found out that japser requires that any user will have the ROLE_USER role.